# Insert image in PDF file using xsl-fo with apache fop 1.1

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Apache Camel + Apache FOP to convert an XML to PDF with using XSL, the project is build with Maven + Java 8

When I try to insert a logo image in the footer of my PDF but I get this error:

*"src" attribute is not allowed on the fo:external-graphic element!*

```
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <fo:external-graphic  src="url(file:///home/someDir/resources/Logo.jpg)" />
                                    </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
```

Comment: `src` is allowed on `fo:external-graphic` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_external-graphic). Can you determine which piece of software is generating the error message?

Comment: because of Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://fo.xsl due to: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "src" attribute is not allowed on the fo:external-graphic element!

Comment: It can be absolute, it is just not a string in their example. The solution posted below is correct but if they simply had src="url('file:///...' in the original it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Or ... simply in your original example:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('file:///home/someDir/resources/Logo.jpg')" />
```

The function url() takes a string. You are not passing it a string as you have not enclosed it in quotes. This is (in reality) all you accomplished by using `<xsl:attribute>` in your solution.

Comment: If I use src attribute like you said I will get ""src" attribute is not allowed on the fo:external-graphic element! "

Comment: The quotes are optional in XSL 1.1 (see '<uri-specification>' in https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#datatype) and the FOP website has examples of 'url()' without quotes (e.g., https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#svg-url).

Comment: Then the OP should try by removing the single quotes in the "solution that works" and test. You will not they are in that sample and not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution that works

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline>
        <fo:external-graphic>
            <xsl:attribute name="content-width">scale-to-fit</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="content-height">200%</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="width">200%</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="scaling">uniform</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">url('file:///home/someDir/resources/Logo.jpg')</xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```